# Navigating back to the original pivot item

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 RT universal app. For my scenario, I have two pages, the first page mainpage.xaml which has a pivot and two pivot items. when I click on a tapped event on a textblock in the second pivot item, I go to the second page. Now if I click the hardware back button, it takes me back to the first pivot item. Shouldn't it take me to the original pivot item where I started my navigation?

I am sure I am missing something very basic here..... :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you can break down the navigation steps as a flow it might be easy to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting NavigationCacheMode on the Page to Enabled? This way the page should be cached so when you go back, the second PivotItem should remain selected.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    NavigationCacheMode="Enabled">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this has resolved the issue of coming back to the originating pivot item but I am seeing some inconsistent behavior in my emulator now. Every time I hit the hardware back button, sometimes, my page reloads and I have to hit the button again to come back to the original pivot item. Thanks

Comment: So what fixed it was a little tweak on what you suggested. I added this line instead and that resolved my issue. ` NavigationCacheMode="Required"` Thanks!